# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Video Production Stack Exchange](http://video.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Should you shoot flat when shooting with a DSLR?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12199/should-you-shoot-flat-when-shooting-with-a-dslr)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cannot mark my video with CC SA licence because Youtube Content ID found 3rd party soundtrack which itself is CC SA licensed](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/cannot-mark-my-video-with-cc-sa-licence-because-youtube-content-id-found-3rd-par)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Will I lose quality when converting avi to mkv?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12171/will-i-lose-quality-when-converting-avi-to-mkv)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Projecting slides on a large screen from 40 feet](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/projecting-slides-on-a-large-screen-from-40-feet)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Audio monitoring w/ headphones through HDMI port](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12084/audio-monitoring-w-headphones-through-hdmi-port)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Benro and Manfrotto Monopods - QR System](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/benro-and-manfrotto-monopods-qr-system)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the name of the device used in live action filming that includes information like scene, take and roll and has a part that can snap together?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/what-is-the-name-of-the-device-used-in-live-action-filming-that-includes-informa)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I update instances of a text template after changing the master template?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12076/how-can-i-update-instances-of-a-text-template-after-changing-the-master-template)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [After Effects - Simple Lighting Effects](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12169/after-effects-simple-lighting-effects)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the name of a portion of video between camera changes?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/what-is-the-name-of-a-portion-of-video-between-camera-changes)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---